# Is there a Firefox installer that removes all references (such as shortcuts) to IE?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet-explorer, installer

I have a lot of clients who would be willing to switch to firefox if only if didn't take so much time to install and configure. 
It takes quite a few phone calls and e-mails for me to make sure they removed all references such as shortcuts on their desktop and start-menu.
They really don't notice any difference at all between browsers, and would be happy to switch if it makes them more secure.

Is anyone aware if a program / installer exists, that will download the latest version of firefox, install it, set is as the default browser, and remove all references to IE?

Comment: More suitable on Super User?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by that. Is Super User an cathegory if can file the question under, or another Q&A site?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: [http://firefox.dbltree.com/][1]
was an interesting read and the option with CLEO is great too, but really the problem is the fact that IE is still on the desktop, and startmenu.

Although giving clients a custom firefox installer would be helpfull too, I'm not sure if it would be 'ok' to include things like flash, silverlight etc. Although I would really want to.
Would this be 'ok' to do ?

`FirefoxSetup.exe /ma` -- (auto-mode, hands-free but visible)
will install firefox without the user's interaction, that's ok, but it leaves the references to IE intact

  [1]: http://firefox.dbltree.com/

Comment: Switching to FF doesn't make anyone more secure. Firefox being safer than IE is a myth and removing "all references to IE" might not be such a good idea at all (or in the best interest of your clients) as there are certain web applications (e.g. many online-banking facilities) that simply do not work with FF.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check out https://wiki.mozilla.org/Deployment:Deploying_Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Two notes for easy install and configuration.

1. `FirefoxSetup.exe /ma`  -- (auto-mode, hands-free but visible)

   - from `MrStatic`'s [reference](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Deployment%3ADeploying%5FFirefox#Installer_Options)
   - Pre-packaged extension set and configurations created with the following two addons
   - [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) -- Firefox Environment Backup Extension
   - [CLEO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2942) -- Compact Library Extension Organizer
   - these two (used in that order after configuring firefox in one place)
     can create a quick install system

Just setup firefox and load it with the single `xpi` package
compacted by **CLEO** from the individual backups from **FEBE**.

Answer (score 0):

> Is anyone aware if a program /
>   installer exists, that will download
>   the latest version of firefox, install
>   it, set is as the default browser, and
>   remove all references to IE?

Yes, it's called **Edskes Software Silent Setup for Mozilla Firefox**, does everything you want and can be found on http://edskes.com/edskesmf/

**Edskes Software Silent Setup for Mozilla Firefox** is a small multilingual utility which **automatically downloads and installs the latest version of Mozilla Firefox**, and then immediately opens one or more websites.

It asks no difficult questions and does not show technical information or error messages and even works under the most restricted user accounts, so **you can quickly use Firefox on any computer and also easily explain how to install Firefox to anyone else**.